# 4x4 Grid of Letters - Word Generator - Scramble with Friends

Tags: ruby, string, algorithm, grid, permutation

I'm attempting to create a word generator based on a 4x4 grid of letters (below).

[image: Scramble with Friends]

Here are the rules:

- Letters cannot be repeated
- Words must be formed by adjacent letters
- Words can be formed horizontally, vertically or diagonally to the left, right or up-and-down

Currently, I take a 16-character input and loop through every word in the dictionary, determining whether that word can be spelled with the letters on the grid.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require './scores'   # alphabet and associated Scrabble scoring value (ie the wordValue() method)
require './words.rb' # dictionary of English words (ie the WORDS array)

# grab users letters
puts "Provide us the 16 letters of your grid (no spaces please)"
word = gets.chomp.downcase

arr = word.split('')

# store words that can be spelled with user's letters
success = []

# iterate through dictionary of words
WORDS.each do |w|

    # create temp arrays
    dict_arr = w.split('')
    user_arr = arr.dup
    test = true

    # test whether users letters spell current word in dict
    while test
        dict_arr.each do |letter|
            if (user_arr.include?(letter))
                i = user_arr.index(letter)
                user_arr.delete_at(i)
            else
                test = false
                break
            end
        end

        # store word in array
        if test 
            success << w
            test = false
        end
    end

end

# create hash for successful words and their corresponding values
SUCCESS = {}

success.each do |w|
  score = wordValue(w)
  SUCCESS[w] = score
end

# sort hash from lowest to smallest value
SUCCESS = SUCCESS.sort_by {|word, value| value}

# print results to screen
SUCCESS.each {|k,v| puts "#{k}:  #{v}"}
```

However, this approach doesn't take into account the positions of the tiles on the board.  **How would you suggest I go about finding words that can be created based on their location in the 4x4 grid?**

For the board game in the image above, it takes about 1.21 seconds for my VM running Ubuntu to compute the 1185 possible words.  I'm using the dictionary of words provided with Ubunut in /usr/share/dict/words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original answer was not what you wanted.  I was creating a list of all of the
"words" in the grid, instead of searching for the words you had already identified
from the dictionary.  Now I have written a function which searches the grid for a
particular word.  It works recursively.

So, now the algorithm is:

1) Get the 16 letters from the user
2) Search dictionary for all words with those letters
3) Call is_word_on_board with each of those words to see if you have a match

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# This script searches a board for a word
#
# A board is represented by a string of letters, for instance, the string
# "abcdefghijklmnop" represents the board:
#
#    a b c d
#    e f g h
#    i j k l
#    m n o p
#
# The array ADJACENT lists the cell numbers that are adjacent to another
# cell.  For instance ADJACENT[3] is [2, 6, 7].  If the cells are numbered
#
#     0  1  2  3
#     4  5  6  7
#     8  9 10 11
#    12 13 14 15

ADJACENT = [
    [1, 4, 5],
    [0, 2, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 3, 5, 6, 7],
    [2, 6, 7],
    [0, 1, 5, 8, 9],
    [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10],
    [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11],
    [2, 3, 6, 10, 11],
    [4, 5, 9, 12, 13],
    [4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14],
    [5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15],
    [6, 7, 10, 14, 15],
    [8, 9, 13],
    [8, 9, 10, 12, 14],
    [9, 10, 11, 13, 15],
    [10, 11, 14]
]

# function:  is_word_on_board
#
# parameters:
#   word   - word you're searching for
#   board  - string of letters representing the board, left to right, top to bottom
#   prefix - partial word found so far
#   cell   - position of last letter chosen on the board
#
# returns true if word was found, false otherwise
#
# Note:  You only need to provide the word and the board.  The other two parameters
# have default values, and are used by the recursive calls.

# set this to true to log the recursive calls
DEBUG = false

def is_word_on_board(word, board, prefix = "", cell = -1)
    if DEBUG
        puts "word = #{word}" 
        puts "board = #{board}"
        puts "prefix = #{prefix}"
        puts "cell = #{cell}"
        puts
    end

    # If we're just beginning, start word at any cell containing
    # the starting letter of the word
    if prefix.length == 0
        0.upto(15) do |i|
            if word[0] == board[i]
                board_copy = board.dup
                newprefix = board[i,1]

                # put "*" in place of letter so we don't reuse it
                board_copy[i] = ?*

                # recurse, and return true if the word is found
                if is_word_on_board(word, board_copy, newprefix, i)
                    return true
                end
            end
        end

        # we got here without finding a match, so return false
        return false
    elsif prefix.length == word.length
        # we have the whole word!
        return true
    else
        # search adjacent cells for the next letter in the word
        ADJACENT[cell].each do |c|
            # if the letter in this adjacent cell matches the next
            # letter of the word, add it to the prefix and recurse
            if board[c] == word[prefix.length]
                newprefix = prefix + board[c, 1]
                board_copy = board.dup

                # put "*" in place of letter so we don't reuse it
                board_copy[c] = ?*

                # recurse, and return true if the word is found
                if is_word_on_board(word, board_copy, newprefix, c)
                    return true
                end
            end
        end

        # bummer, no word found, so return false
        return false
    end
end

puts "Test board:"
puts
puts "  r u t t"
puts "  y b s i"
puts "  e a r o"
puts "  g h o l"
puts

board = "ruttybsiearoghol"

for word in ["ruby", "bears", "honey", "beast", "rusty", "burb", "bras", "ruttisbyearolohg", "i"]
    if is_word_on_board(word, board)
        puts word + " is on the board"
    else
        puts word + " is NOT on the board"
    end
end
```

Running this script give the following results:

```
Test board:

  r u t t
  y b s i
  e a r o
  g h o l

ruby is on the board
bears is on the board
honey is NOT on the board
beast is on the board
rusty is NOT on the board
burb is NOT on the board
bras is on the board
ruttisbyearolohg is on the board
i is on the board
```

Comment: On my 4 year old Mac running Ruby 1.8.7, is_word_on_board is able to check 20,000 words a second, so I don't think speed is a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of iterating over words and searching for their presence, walk through each tile on the grid and find all words stemming from that tile.

First, compile your dictionary into a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  Tries are efficient at performing prefix-matching string comparisons, which will be of use to us shortly.

To find the words within the board, perform the following steps for each of the 16 tiles, starting with an empty string for `prefix`.

1. Add the current tile's  value to `prefix`.
2. Check if our trie contains any words starting with `prefix`.
3. If it does, branch the search: for each legal (unvisited) tile that is adjacent to this tile, go back to step 1 (recurse).
4. If it doesn't match, stop this branch of the search since there are no matching words.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a simple graph representing the whole board. Letters would be vertices. If two letters are near one another on the board I would create an edge between their vertices. It would be very easy to find out whether the input is valid. You simply would have to check whether there is a matching path in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have a Boggle solver I wrote a while ago. It follows Cheeken's outline. It's invoked a bit differently (you supply the word list file and a text file with a 4x4 grid as arguments), but I figured it was worth sharing. Also note that it treats "Q" as "QU", so there's some extra logic in there for that.

```
require 'set'

def build_dict(dict, key, value)
  if key.length == 0
    dict[:a] = value
  else
    if key[0] == "q"
      first = key[0..1]
      rest = key[2, key.length - 1]
    else
      first = key[0]
      rest = key[1, key.length - 1]
    end

    dict[first] = {} unless dict.has_key? first
    build_dict(dict[first], rest, value)
  end
end

dict = {}
#parse the file into a dictionary
File.open(ARGV[0]).each_line do |line|
  real_line = line.strip
  build_dict(dict, real_line, real_line)
end

#parse the board
board = {}
j = 0
File.open(ARGV[1]).each_line do |line|
  line.chars.each_with_index do |l, i|
    board[[j, i]] = l
  end
  j += 1
end

#(0..3).each{|r| puts (0..3).map{|c| board[[r, c]]}.join}

#how can i get from one place to another?
def get_neighbors(slot, sofar)
  r, c = slot
  directions =
   [
    [r+1, c],
    [r+1, c+1],
    [r+1, c-1],
    [r, c+1],
    [r, c-1],
    [r-1, c],
    [r-1, c+1],
    [r-1, c-1]
   ]
  directions.select{|a| a.all?{|d| d >= 0 && d <= 3} && !sofar.include?(a)}
end

#actual work
def solve(board, slot, word_dict, sofar)
  results = Set.new
  letter = board[slot]
  letter = "qu" if letter == "q"
  stuff = word_dict[letter]
  return results if stuff.nil?
  if stuff.has_key? :a
    results << stuff[:a] if stuff[:a].length > 2
  end
  unless stuff.keys.select{|key| key != :a}.empty?
    get_neighbors(slot, sofar).each do |dir|
      results += solve(board, dir, stuff, sofar.clone << slot)
    end
  end
  results
end

#do it!
results = Set.new
all_slots = (0..3).to_a.product((0..3).to_a)
all_slots.each do |slot|
  results += solve(board, slot, dict, slot)
end

puts results.sort
```